# Swapping in divs with Django Web Framework

Tags: jquery, django, templates, uiview, django-templates

I'm a beginner and I have a web app design that is broken up into three rectangles (top, middle, bottom). If a user has javascript, clicking a link causes one or two of the rectangles to be swapped out using jQuery and if the user does not (i.e. web crawler), clicking a link reloads the entire page leaving everything the same except for those one or two rectangles.

How would you implement a layout like this with Django? I don't want to have to hard-code in anything.

Or am I using the wrong tool?

Comment: Django does not write Javascript for you but can dynamically render templates that include Javascript. 

With Django templates, using {% includes 'some_template.html' %} and template tags you can render each box individually with whatever dynamic variables you wish. This requires you render Javascript through Django (easiest by using inline Javascript, which isn't exactly best practice). 

Django CAN do this and especially assist if there are dynamic values to supply to Javascript, but this isn't a situation where someone would consider the 'best-fit' tool.

Comment: @IanPrice - What is the 'best-fit' tool?

Comment: It depends on what the other requirements of the application are. Django can do many things but is specifically made for database-driven web applications with a need for backend processing. 

Django essentially being a back-end framework does NOT preclude you from using a front-end/JS framework and they can play nicely together. In short, Django's templating engine can work WITH what you are requesting but can not do it FOR you; neither can any other back-end framework such as RoR.

Comment: Well I need a database-driven web application, and I need search engine optimization to work for every search engine (not just the fancy google javascript executing web crawler), and I want the visual pleasantness of not having to do full page reloads when like 25% of the page is unmodified from one page to the next. I don't like Rails. Considering Lift framework, but so hard to set up.

Comment: I don't think I need a full front end framework because I don't really have a desktop style application with moving pieces all over. Just a really smooth series of web pages. Never used Angular but a lot of those frameworks seem like overkill. In the absence of any other answer, I think I'll just put all the javascript code for loading divs and changing the URL into the HTML templates directly.

Comment: Oh, also, the javascript code has to launch a "clicked" event to google analytics. So I would put the click event, the jquery ajax load, and the click event all inside the Django templates.

Comment: Yes, or include separate JS files (supplied by Django's static files) within the template.

As far as analytics, there's Django tools to make that easy; see https://github.com/jcassee/django-analytical. 

I'd suggest doing some more tutorials related to Django's template language and template rendering.

Comment: To Add- Django can supply responses to Ajax calls easilythrough many methods but how they are rendered to the user requires a JS specific solutioj